# Do isomorphic rings have isomorphic localizations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be commutative rings with identity. Let $S\subset A$ be a multiplicative subset. Suppose that there is an automorphism $f:A\cong A$. Then can $f$ induces an automorphism $S^{-1}A\cong S^{-1}A$?

I think this is incorrect. If $A$ is a perfect ring, consider the isomorphic Frobenius $A\rightarrow A,a\mapsto a^{p}$. Take $S=\{1,g,...,g^{n},...\},g\in A$. Then for $g\in S$, one may not find some $f_{0}\in S$ with $f_{0}^{p}=g$. This shows that the Frobenius $A_{g}\rightarrow A_{g},a/b\mapsto a^{p}/b^{p}$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: You need some connection between $S$ and $H$.

Comment: @Randall: Sorry that... I have editted my question more concretely.

Comment: You should expect $S^{-1}A$ to be iso to $f(S)^{-1}A$.

Comment: Actually, in your example, there is some $f_0 \in A$ such that $f=f_0^p$, and the inverse image of $a/f^n$ is $a’f_0^{(p-1)n}/f^n$, where $a’^p=a$.

Comment: @Aphelli: Could you give a short proof?

Comment: @Randall: It seems that one can not show that $f|_{S}:S\rightarrow S$ is bijective. But $f(S)^{-1}A$ is clearly isomorphic to $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: You seem to be using $f$ to mean quite different things, the automorphism of $A$ in the first paragraph and an element of the multiplicative set $S \subset A$ in the second paragraph.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks for your reminder!

Comment: @ToneyLeung: just compute the image of my element under the Fronebius.

Comment: @Aphelli: Got it!

Comment: @hardmath: Ok! Frankly, $g\in S$ is better.